# Unable to use custom rule defined in custom form validation file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have extended the Codeigniter form_validation library and made a custom validation library which is as follows

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {
    protected $CI;
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
                // reference to the CodeIgniter super object 
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

        public function check($str) {           
         $this->CI->form_validation->set_message('check', 'The %s is not valid.');
           return FALSE;

       }
}
```

And calling it in the controller as shown below

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('officerLastName', 'officerLastName', 'check');
```

But I'm not getting any error and the form is getting submitted

any suggestion on where i went wrong would be great
and also i wanted to know whether the same thing can be used for the rule_group defined in config folder

Comment: if ($this->form_validation->run() != True) {$this->load->view(); }

Comment: @satishrajak  i am running the validation                                                  if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {$this->index();} else
        { //success }

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('officerLastName', 'officerLastName', 'callback_check');

public function check($str) {
    .........
}
```

Comment: I had previously Used Callback method,but  i wanted to build my own custom library so that i can have access to the rule throughout the application without repeating myself in the controller